# math.log() :TypeError: must be real number, not GKVariable

Tags: python

I'm using  python 3.6 math.log() function to get natural logarithm of an array of 4381 records. [Here is my complete array](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WNwWrb_qPSDieODKAT-f7vnpPtiaJ6ac/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using following code in python to get natural log

```
math.log(a)
```

I'm getting error message as `TypeError: must be real number, not GKVariable`
For the same number I can able to do natural logarithm in excel.Can you suggest me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question. Surely you can make one without needing that large list of numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Besides the MVCE, we expect your posting to be self-contained; a link to an off-site item is generally not accepted.

Comment: @Prune. I didn't want to put link to an off site.But I could not able to add all the numbers here as it was crossing maximum limit of SO. It's midnight in my time zone. I need to solve this by morning tomorrow. So I wanted to put the complete array here so that experts from SO can able to guide me a solution.

Comment: Again, refer to the MCVE description.  You should be able to reproduce the problem for us with a small subset of your list.  Also refer to the posting guidelines: your time urgency does not excuse violating the guidelines.  The site charter is for lasting issues, not short-term help.

Comment: What do you want to with log after? As it says `log` takes number, not... idk what is GKVariable. You might use `logs = [math.log(i) for i in a]`.

Comment: For one thing, `math.log` takes a float, not a list of floats.  Perhaps you want to apply numpy.log to a numpy array?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation:
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html][1]

The `math.log()` function receive as argument a number, and not a list of numbers.

I don't understand why you are getting a `TypeError: must be real number, not GKVariable`, I'm getting `TypeError: must be real number, not list`\

In any case, you can just do:

```
result = [math.log(i) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

`math.log` takes a float as input. You gave it a list. Numpy's log can handle numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array(YOUR_LIST)
loga = np.log(a)
```

If you don't want to use numpy, you will have to use list comprehension:

```
loga = [math.log(i) for i in a]
```